Revit API plugin submission - subscription without using the Entitlement API
I'm currently in the final stages of preparing to submit my first Revit plug-in (Desktop App) to the Autodesk App Store, and I have a few questions that I'd greatly appreciate some help with.
I'm seeking clarification on handling subscribers without implementing the Entitlement API. Is this even feasible? My goal is to offer monthly/yearly payment options. When submitting the app, Autodesk only requests a PayPal account and mentions that implementing the Entitlement API is mandatory only if you intend to publish a trial version. Essentially, I'm inquiring whether it's possible to handle subscribers without this API, and if so, are there any specific preparations I need to make in my code?
Could anyone please shed some light on this or direct me to any relevant information?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Have you discussed this with the AppStore team? You can reach them at appsubmissions@autodesk.com. You might also find some info in the Revit API discussion forum threads on Revit Entitlement API and more recently and specifically Licencing Plugins - What Revit subscriptions have to be considered? ... and others, of course.

Hey Jeremy,
Thank you for your help! I appreciate your response.
I'll definitely take a look at the Licensing Plugins thread. Before reaching out to their team, I thought it would be beneficial to gather some information on my end. That's my next step.
Thanks once again for your help!

It might be better to check with AD Support first, especially since there might be restrictions and limitations on what you can do within the confines of the licensing model you're bound to - making sure what you're doing is OK before asking how to circumvent an entire API is definitely the safer option here
